# Vuforia & Unity 1.5 not rendering object on the scene on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, qcar-sdk

I am very frustrated with this problem and the Unity3D community isn't very helpful because no one there is answering my question. I have done a ton of searching to find what the problem could be, but I didn't succeed. I install Qualcomm Vuforia 1.5 and Unity3D 1.5.0.f. I use the Unity extension. I imported their demo app called vuforia-imagetargets-android-1-5-10.unitypackage, put their wood chips image target on the scene, their AR camera, and added a box object on top of the image target. Then I built it and sent to my Samsung Galaxy tablet. However, when I open the app on the tablet and point the tablet to the image target, nothing shows up - the box isn't there. As if I didn't add any objects to the scene. I just see what the device camera sees.

Has anybody experienced this before? Do you have any ideas what could be wrong? No one online seems to be complaining about it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have your ImageTarget dataset activated and loaded for your ARCamera (in the inspector, under Data Set Load Behaviour) and that the checkbox next to the Camera subheading in the inspector is ticked.

Also ensure that the cube (or other 3d object) is a child of ImageTarget in the hierarchy, and that your ImageTarget object has it's "Image Target Behaviour" set to the intended image.

You may also have to point your ARCamera in such a way that your scene is not visible to it.

Comment: I downloaded the latest Vuforia AR and I attached it on Unity 3D. However, when I run it and it appears nothing but black. When I check the *Image Target Behaviour* script, I don't seen the Data Set and it replaces with a button that labeled *No targets defined. Press here for target creation!* and this where I have to login for database.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I got the solution. I asked on Qualcomm's forum and one gentleman was nice enough to explain to me that I missed setting up Data Set Load Behaviour in Unity's AR camera. I had to active the image target data set and load the corresponding image target. Once I set these two things up, built and deployed, all worked well.

Good luck!

Comment: How do you active the image target data set?